# Button Click not working After Ajax call in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Button is working before ajax call in bootstrap Modal.
But After Ajax call click event is not working.

```
function book_appointment_timeslot(job_id,planner_date,time_slot,contract_id){    
       $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/add_appointment_planner",
                  data: { contract_id: contract_id,job_id : job_id,  planner_date: planner_date, time_slot: time_slot, _token: CSRF_TOKEN },  
                  success: function(data){
                         if(data['status']=='success')
                         {
                                show_notification(data['status'],data['message']);
                                $("#apt_status_table").load(location.href + " #apt_status_table");
                                $(".tbl_planner_list_whole").load(location.href + " .tbl_planner_list_whole");

                         }
                  }
    });
}
```

I Have tried below solutions ,

Solution-1 :-

```
$(document).on('click', '.appointment_edit_button', function(){
    alert("success");
});
```

Solution-2 :-

```
$(document).delegate('click', '.appointment_edit_button', function(){
    alert("success");
});
```

I tried with `unbind()` also. It also not working.
When I put script directly in Console. Then it's working. So may be it's due to bootstrap modal.

So, I want to **enable button click event after ajax call in bootstrap modal**.

EDIT :-

HTML Code :-

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="agenda-date">
                                    <div class="dayofmonth color_font_date">2017-06-01</div>
                                    <div class="dayofweek">
                                        thursday                                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="row margin_two_planner">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="book_appointment_timeslot(19,&quot;2017-06-01&quot;,
                                            1,43)">am </button> 
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#add_apt_status" class=""><input type="number" value="8" name="" class="number_planner"></a>
                                        <input type="number" value="9" name="" class="max_limit" disabled="">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="am" name="" class="timeslot_max_limit" disabled="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row margin_two_planner">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="book_appointment_timeslot(19,&quot;2017-06-01&quot;,
                                            2,43)">pm </button> 
                                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#add_apt_status" class=""><input type="number" value="6" name="" class="number_planner"></a>
                                        <input type="number" value="5" name="" class="max_limit" disabled="">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="pm" name="" class="timeslot_max_limit" disabled="">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 20%;"> 
                                    <textarea id="" class="form-control initial_cap appointment_note" required="required" rows="3" name="appointment_note" cols="50" aria-required="true" disabled="">       asdsad             </textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 20%;"> 
                                <textarea id="" class="form-control initial_cap holiday_note" required="required" rows="3" name="holiday_note" cols="50" aria-required="true" disabled="">       asasdsaddsad        </textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="text-right">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="planner_date" name="" value="2017-06-01">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="contract_id" name="" value="43">
                                    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-primary appointment_edit_button">edit </button>
                                    <button type="button" id="" onclick="planner_note_edit(10,event)" class="btn btn-md btn-primary appointment_update_button" style="display:none"> update </button>
                                    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-md btn-cancel appointment_cancel_button" style="display:none">cancel </button>
                            </div>
                            </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Through this appointment_edit_button class I'm doing this process.

```
$(".appointment_edit_button").on("click",function(event) {   
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".appointment_note").prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".holiday_note").prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".max_limit").prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).next('button').show();
        $(this).next('button').next('button').show();
        $(this).hide();
});
```

I looks like. 
[image]

Comment: After load what html is there in your div? can you share that?

Comment: @AlivetoDie. Yeah sure I'm updating my question.

Comment: The click code you tried is inside function `book_appointment_timeslot` or outside?

Comment: Can you please post your html code?

Comment: You have to re-initialize click event after ajax response check here: http://jsfiddle.net/6VtA8/. Hope this will help you!

Comment: @AlivetoDie. No it's outside the function `book_appointment_timeslot()`.

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava. I already tried it it's not working `on()` or `delegate()` is not working. it's working in console but not in code.

Comment: @Bhavin  it's coming in pop-up? if yes then what's the pop-up container id or class

Comment: Yeah it's coming in pop-up. Bootstrap pop-up's id is `list_appointment`. Can we call any event of bootstrap modal first and then enable click event ?

Comment: @Bhavin  try to use:- `$('#list_appointment').on('click', '.appointment_edit_button', function(){
    alert("success");
});`

Comment: @AlivetoDie. Thank you for your reply. I just tried your code It's not working. It's perfectly working directly on console. But after ajax call it's not working. I have tried with `setTimeout()` with 2 second but no luck brother.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your dom is manipulated by that ajax success callback so the click event registration is removed. Try to bind the click event again in the ajax callback.

```
function book_appointment_timeslot(job_id,planner_date,time_slot,contract_id){    
   $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/add_appointment_planner",
              data: { contract_id: contract_id,job_id : job_id,  planner_date: planner_date, time_slot: time_slot, _token: CSRF_TOKEN },  
              success: function(data){
                     if(data['status']=='success')
                     {
                            show_notification(data['status'],data['message']);
                            $("#apt_status_table").load(location.href + " #apt_status_table");
                            $(".tbl_planner_list_whole").load(location.href + " .tbl_planner_list_whole");
                            $('.appointment_edit_button').click(function(){alert("success");});

                     }
              }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried it. it's not working.

Comment: Well do you have any console errors? What is the output of `$('.appointment_edit_button')` when you register the event?

Answer (score 0):

After ajax response, your binding to div for specific call (click in your case) is removed as DOM area is loaded. Try to initialize your bindings again in ajax response success.

Comment: Try to add some code snippet to express the concept :)

Comment: Try to add this click even again from ajax response
$(".appointment_edit_button").on("click",function(event) {   
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".appointment_note").prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".holiday_note").prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".max_limit").prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).next('button').show();
        $(this).next('button').next('button').show();
        $(this).hide();
});